# Dragonfire - Gorgon Encounter

Tags: dragonfire

In Dragonfire, the Gorgon Encounter has the following Tripwire:

> Terror: Can only play one card; cannot Assist.

Say that the '5' level of the damage track was already cleared, and on my current turn I then clear the '2' level. Can I play one card from this point, or is the Terror retroactive?

Comment: Perhaps your question is more clear to players of the game, but does clearing a level remove a card/effect from play?

Comment: @ryanyuyu No, it clears one level from the encounter's damage track. I'll try to make my question more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the Tripwires are retroactive, but as per the turn order you are not able to play cards after the Gorgons Terror tripwire has triggered.
This is also detailed in the [Errata and FAQ](https://dragonfirethegame.com/downloads/Dragonfire_FAQ_Errata.pdf):

> **Q:** Is the Terror Tripwire keyword an ongoing effect?
> **A:** Yes, Terror is an ongoing effect once it has been activated.
> However, remember that the Apply Damage phase occurs after
> the Play Cards phase, so if you’re going to trip the Terror Tripwire
> on a turn, you’ll get to play cards as normal on that turn, since the
> keyword won’t come into effect until the Take Damage phase of
> your turn.